# How to substitute elements in an HTML template

Tags: java, android, html

I have an HTML template consisting of various HTML tags and styling applied. I want to substitute values  text/URLs in anchor tag etc within this HTML template, with the variables values that I am getting in my java method during runtime.

Reading HTML template file is not difficult but how should I go ahead with adding various element to the this HTML template. Need the best approach. Also I will be using this code in Android and I want to limit the size of my build to bare minimum, so probably can't use a web template engine.

Answer (score 0):

Well as general as the question here is my general answer:

If the template you have is well formed i would start going throught it with STAX and enrich ("substitute values") it with your data using STAX (Or DOM Parser) to get the desired output HTML.

If it is not well formed id go for Librarys like JSoup, TagSoup and so on to at least have a base for the parsing (i assume the enrichment/ replacement you want to do is not handable by those librarys).

You do it by hand (StringBuffers, Strings and a whole lot of didadum that will cause more and more trubles over time).